# Django: empty comment form error handling

Tags: django, forms, redirect, comments

I use standart django comments framework.

template:

```
<h2>Add comment</h2> {%  get_comment_form for post as form %} 
<form  action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post" > {% csrf_token %}   
{{form.content_type}}{{form.object_pk}}{{form.timestamp}}{{form.security_hash}}
Comment:<br />
{{form.comment}}

<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}#comment" /> 

<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Post</button>

</form>
```

urls:

```
(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
```

Then I send empty form, I redirect to /comments/post/ page.
How can I just reload current page and add error message? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

That is the proper behavior. See `<form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">`? Your form submits to the url `/comments/post/` page so even if it is blank, you will end up there. What you need to do is add some sort of handling to the view for `/comments/post/` that will redirect you to the original page with a message telling the user to fill out the form if it is incomplete or incorrect. Django does that normally though, so I don't know what's different here.